# Ensure that maven releases are always made from a specific branch

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

Is there a way to ensure that that I'm on master when doing a release using the maven release plugin? I'd like it to check this so that I can not create a release on a different branch by mistake. I'm using a git repository btw.

Comment: Are you calling release plugin manually from plain command line or from a CI solution like Jenkins?

Comment: @khmarbaise from the command line.

Comment: I would always recommend to make releases from within a CI solution never manually by hand or on a dev machine...Apart from that you can use a combination of buildnumber-maven-plugin and maven-enforcer-plugin to handle this. The simplest solution which comes into my mind is a simple bash script...